# Is this set a vector space and if not, why?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Determine if the following is a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) under the given
operations. If not, list some of the [axioms that fail to hold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition).

The set of all triples of real numbers $(x, y, z)$ with the operations
$$(x, y, z) + (x'
, y'
, z'
) = (x + x
'
, y + y
'
, z + z
'
)$$

and

$$λ(x, y, z) = (λx, y, z)$$

Comment: Hint: what is $0 \times (0,1,0)$?

Comment: that sounds like a homework question. What work have you done so far?

Comment: @Oct18isdayofsilenceonSE it is a worksheet from the week I missed classes. I am just confused with $x'$ values, which I have not seen on the tutorials I have been going through. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Mindlack Should be zero right?

Comment: "x\`" is just a name for a variable, i suppose. You can replace "x\`" with "A"

Comment: @SarpSTA: well, try with the definition.

Comment: @Oct18isdayofsilenceonSE Oh so it is just named that way because it represents the x part of another vector? Makes sense then.

Comment: @Mindlack I think I lack the knowledge about that.

Comment: So I say u = (x,y,z) and v=(x′,y′,z′) and V = (x+x′,y+y′,z+z′) then?

Comment: @SarpSTA: by the definition, $0 \times (0,1,0)=(0 \times 0,1,0)=(0,1,0)$ isn’t neutral for the addition, so it’s not a vector space.

Comment: @Mindlack Oh. So normally, it *should* be (0,0,0) but according to the definition, it should be (0,1,0), which is incorrect and therefore not a vector space?

Comment: The thing is that in a vector space, $0$ times a vector must be the neutral element for the additive group law (ie $0 \cdot v+w =w$ for all $w,v$). Here, it clearly isn’t the case.

Comment: @Mindlack So these sum and multiply operations are not the traditional ones but rather redifined per the question as described above?

Comment: Yes, that’s precisely it.

Comment: @Mindlack Could you please post as answer so I can accept?

Comment: A vector space on which field? this has n't been determined.

Comment: @MaryamAjorlou Such as what? I thought triples of real numbers was the field.

Comment: @SarpSTA, I meant according to the definition, one should say, where scalers, namely $\lambda$'s, come from.

Comment: @MaryamAjorlou They weren't present in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no it is not. and there is two of the axioms that fail to hold:

1) Associativity of addition:

this axiom requires : *u+(v+w) = (u+v)+w* so if we assume that *u = v = (x,y,z)* and *w = (x',y',z')*

then based on the space property, for the left side of equation we will have:

*(x,y,z) + ((x,y,z)+(x',y',z')) = (x,y,z) + ((x+x',y+y',z+z')) = (2x+x',2y+y',2z+z')*

and for the right side of equation we will have:

*((x,y,z) + (x,y,z))+(x',y',z') = 2(x,y,z) + (x',y',z') = (2x+x',y+y',z+z')*

so:

*(x,y,z) + ((x,y,z)+(x',y',z'))* is not equal to *((x,y,z) + (x,y,z))+(x',y',z')*

and this axiom fails to hold.

2)Inverse elements of addition:

For every *v ∈ V*, there exists an element *−v ∈ V*, called the additive inverse of *v*, such that *v + (−v) = 0*.

but in this space if we assume *v = (x,y,z)* then:

*v + (-v) = (x,y,z) + (-1(x,y,z)) = (x,y,z)+(-x,y,z) = (0,2y,2z)* which is not equal to 0.

Comment: Associativity of addition still holds here. It is the same addition as $\mathbb{R}^3$.  The identity $(x,y,z) + (x,y,z) = 2(x,y,z)$ that you used does not hold in this space.

Comment: the identity that i used is the rule of this space you cant neglect that. @JairTaylor

Comment: It's an identity of a vector space, but this is not a vector space. However, you could use your (1) as a proof by contradiction that is is not a vector space, since you've shown that if the axioms of a vector space hold then associativity of addition fails, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose scalers come from $\mathbb{R}$.

A counterexample for not being a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ : 
$v=(3,4,5)$ , $\lambda_{1}= 1$ , $\lambda_{2}= 2$

Then, $(\lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2} )v= (1+2)(3,4,5)=3(3,4,5)= (9,4,5 )$

But On the other side : $\lambda_{1}v + \lambda_{2}v= 1 ( 3,4,5) +2 (3,4,5)= ( 3,4,5) + ( 6,4,5)= ( 9,8,10)$

Namely, $(\lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2} )v\neq\lambda_{1}v + \lambda_{2}v$